# Attaching user data to AXObserver

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I am using an AXObserver to monitor when a window is closed.  In the callback, I am just raising an NSNotification.  All working well.

What is the correct syntax for attaching some user data as refcon?  The working call looks like this:

```
err6 = AXObserverAddNotification(observerTable, tableRef, kAXUIElementDestroyedNotification, nil);
```

and the callback specified when I create the observer has the signature:

```
static void cbTableClosed (AXObserverRef observer, AXUIElementRef element, CFStringRef notification, void *refcon)
```

I want to replace refcon with an object of my own, but don't know how to change either line.  The obvious objective-c type changes through up warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the object's `id` to `void *` when adding the observer, and cast back to the specific object type (`MyObject *`) within the `cbTableClosed` function body.